# How to recursively find big files in a directory on a Windows 7 operating system

Tags: windows-7

IT is on my case. They say I am using too much hard drive space, and need to use less.

I start looking for the culprits which are huge and are the cause.  Problem is I have multiple nested directories, and am having a hard time finding them.

How can I do find the big files in a given directory and its sub-directories?  Ideally, I would be able to sort them from large to small.

Thanks

Comment: @gronostaj.  Thanks, WinDirStat seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) and [Spacesniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) are both great tools for this. I particularly like the visual presentation in Spacesniffer although it is very memory intensive as it updates in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

One word (er, two) [SpaceMonger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/download/)... There are other tools, but this one is dear to me.